# Getting rid of backtrack 5?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, backtrack

I recently installed backtrack 5 onto my hard drive using the installer program after booting from a usb. The installer program allocated 400 gb of space and now i'm out of room for windows. How do I uninstall backtrack 5 and reallocate the 400 gb to windows? I downloaded gparted onto a bootable usb but I got the error that partitioning the drive may not allow me to boot windows again. How can I undo the install?

Comment: also, if i can't boot windows and end up having to boot from a windows 7 disk, will my previous data be saved? so basically, will partitioning the backtrack space mess up my windows data?

Comment: There's no such thing like "uninstall" backtrack, you could run windows installation disc in order to repair your windows, and then inside windows use partition magic or something like that to delete the backtrack partition and at the end, extend the partition of windows to the remaining space